# what the $resourceURI should be?

Tags: azure-managed-identity

We have an azure webapp which is configured Managed Service Identity. We also have a keyvault which we configured with some secrets. The Managed Service Identity account was granted access to the keyvault. I'm basically trying to validate the webapp can connect to the keyvault and read the secrets. I found the below powershell examples but I'm not following what the `$resourceURI` should be. Is that the webapp?

```
$apiVersion = "2017-09-01"
$resourceURI = "https://<AAD-resource-URI-for-resource-to-obtain-token>"
$tokenAuthURI = $env:MSI_ENDPOINT + "?resource=$resourceURI&api-version=$apiVersion"
$tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Headers @{"Secret"="$env:MSI_SECRET"} -Uri $tokenAuthURI
$accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need a token for Key Vault, $resourceURI should be https://vault.azure.net/

Feel free to check out our tutorials at: aka.ms/azuremsi

Hope this helps.
-Arturo